# Magento 2 | How to include third party library by adding at 'lib/'?

Tags: magento2, 3rd-party-library, autoloader, required

This is not about adding by composer. This is about downloading and then using it.
For Example: I download TCPDF Library and follows [these](https://edmondscommerce.github.io/magento/using-tcpdf-with-magento.html) steps it should be installed and usable but it doesn't works as explained.

When we need use this line?

```
require_once DIR . '/../../../../../lib/folder/folder/ntlmstream.php';
```

What is the Role of autoload?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way I figured for TCPDF Library:

1. Download TCPDF from https://github.com/tecnickcom/tcpdf
2. Change the name of the file root directory after extraction to TCPDF
3. Inside this directory, there is a tcpdf.php file, change the name to TCPDF
4. Open the file and change the class name from tcpdf to TCPDF_TCPDF
5. Copy the files into your Magento “lib/internal” folder in the root Magento installation directory.

=>So it should look like this: lib/internal/TCPDF

Now, write below statement in the class where you want to make tcpdf object:

```
require_once('lib/internal/TCPDF/TCPDF.php');
```

And use this class as:

```
$tcpdf = new \TCPDF_TCPDF();
```

Example Code is:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Generatepdf;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

require_once('lib/internal/TCPDF/TCPDF.php');

class CreatePdf extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action  {

protected $_dir;
protected $customerName;
protected $order;
public function __construct(
Context $context,
Order $order,
DirectoryList $dir

)
{
$this->order = $order;
$this->_dir = $dir;

parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute() {

$tcpdf = new \TCPDF_TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$tcpdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);

$tcpdf->SetTitle('Title');

$tcpdf->setPrintHeader(false);

$tcpdf->setPrintFooter(false);


// set default monospaced font

$tcpdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);


// set margins

$tcpdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);

$tcpdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);

$tcpdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);


// set auto page breaks

$tcpdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);


// set image scale factor

$tcpdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);


// set some language-dependent strings (optional)

if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lang/eng.php')) {

    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lang/eng.php');

    $tcpdf->setLanguageArray($l);

}

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set default font subsetting mode

$tcpdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

//your htmls here

$html=$this->getHtml();

// set some language dependent data:

$lg = Array();

$lg['a_meta_charset'] = 'UTF-8';


$tcpdf->setLanguageArray($lg);


// set font

//dejavusans & freesans For Indian Rupees symbol

$tcpdf->SetFont('freesans', '', 12);

// remove default header/footer

//$tcpdf->setPrintHeader(false);

$tcpdf->setPrintFooter(false);


$tcpdf->AddPage();


$tcpdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');


$tcpdf->lastPage();

//$tcpdf->Output('report_per_route.pdf', 'I');

//$this->logger->debug('report_per_route');
$baseurl = $this->getDirPath();
$filename = $baseurl .'/export/'. 'Sample_pdf'. time().'.pdf';
$tcpdf->Output($filename, 'I');
}

}
?>
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I havent tried your way till now, but I have a question, Is there any way to bind it in custom module under m2root/app/code/name_space/ ?

Comment: I tried by binding it in custom module but TCPDF lib was not responding. But I think their must be a way like that.. Above is perfectly working way. You try if it works then share the way here as well.

Comment: What if the class you are trying to run is withing a subfolder? An example is Phpseclib2. Full path is "/lib/internal/phpseclib2/Net/SFTP.php".

Answer (score 0):

I wanna to add some information for Ajwad Syed answer. You can add this

```
require_once(BP . '/lib/internal/TCPDF/TCPDF.php');
```

to registration.php of your module and it will be work and it works correctly because for nginx require_once('lib/internal/TCPDF/TCPDF.php'); dont work, because pub the main dir of index.php and it search lib/internal/TCPDF/TCPDF.php in pub dir. Maybe for somebody will be usefull